# desktopcouches don't pair

Tags: 11.10, couchdb, desktopcouch, avahi

I'm a rather advanced Ubuntu user and I'd like to develop things that will use desktopcouch, but I can't get started because the seemingly simple task of pairing two couches in my local network doesn't work. When I look in the avahi browser I can see the couches and even the invitation listeners.

As I understand the tool `desktopcouch-pair` I just have to start the invitation listening and I should be able to pair the couches. But nothing happens ... and to be honest, I don't even understand how the couches will stay in sync when they are started using random ports each time.

I hope I can get some explanation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use [U1DB](https://launchpad.net/u1db) instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you pair two desktopcouch instances, what happens is that the first db stores the information about the second, and syncs *from* it, and the second stores information about the first and syncs *from* that. Of course, the sync is two-way, but the point is that both will try to connect to the other. This will work as long as not both of the servers change IP address at the same time. If that happens, you'll have to ... re(-)pair them. :)

The information is stored in each couchdb management database, so have a look in your Futons and see if the information is correct.

Comment: But the port is relevant too, isn't it? If both couchdb instances start on other ports each time, how are they able to find each other? ... And: were you able to pair your desktopcouches?

Comment: I just read that desktopcouch is dead ... so to say. Why didn't you tell me? I read your posts on the mailing list (and although I didn't read everything I kind of agree with your anger). But if you don't have any strong issues against it I will give U1DB a try ;)

Comment: None. However, desktopcouch isn't dead. It's just not supported by Canonical anymore. CouchDB is very much alive though. You only need desktopcouch and similar if you have several users on your desktop/laptop. If you only have one or a few users, then CouchDB is just as easy, or actually easier.